# Array structure not working correctly

Tags: c, hash, struct, segmentation-fault

I have an array which has a key and info for each index in the array.

This builds the array

```
table_t *table_construct (int table_size, int probe_type)
{
    int i;
    table_t *hash;
    if(table_size < 1) return NULL;

    hash = malloc(sizeof(table_t));
    hash->table = malloc(sizeof(list_t*) * table_size);
    for(i=0; i < table_size - 1; i++)
    {
        hash->table[i] = NULL;
        //hash->table[i]->next = NULL;
    }
    hash->size = table_size;
    hash->probing_type = probe_type;
    return hash;
}
```

So I have the list_t and the table_t structures. I have the following line in my code that is not working correctly:

```
hash->table[item]->K = K;
```

It can be seen in this part of my code:

```
int dec, item, hold;
       item = hashing(hash,K);
       hold = item;
       if(hash->table[item] == NULL)
       {
            hash->table[item]->K = K;
            hash->table[item]->I = I;
            return 0;
       }
```

When I GDB it, K is a number.

So what is happening here is, I have my table which is indexed with item. Then I add K to the key of the index. When ever this line comes up anywhere in my program I get a seg Fault.

Can you see anything Ive done wrong here?

Comment: Well, did you allocate memory for your `table` array? And then did you allocate memory for each individual `list_t` object pointed from `table` elements? You have to show us how you do it.

Comment: Without knowing how you allocate items in `table` it's going to be hard to help...

Comment: Ill add my construct function right now.

Comment: So far you haven't shown `hash->table[i]` being set to anything apart from NULL...

Comment: I added where I do the line. Item is 0 when I first try it

Comment: @John3136 is right.  You allocated an array of null pointers. (Actually you missed the last one.  Remove the `- 1` from the `for` loop condition.) So `hash->table[i]` is dereferencing anull pointer. Additionally, types ending in `_t` are reserved by the C Standard.  You're risking name clashes with system libraries.

Comment: So would I not set each one to NULL in my construct function?

Comment: Or do I have to malloc each index of the array?

Answer (score 1):

You verified your pointer is null, so before you can reference off it you need to assign it something:

```
   if(hash->table[item] == NULL)
   {
        hash->table[item] = malloc(sizeof(list_t)); // you were missing this.
        hash->table[item]->K = K;
        hash->table[item]->I = I;
        return 0;
   }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Can I just add that line to my construct function?

Comment: Also this line seg faults.

Answer (score 0):

According to what you posted in your `table_construct` function, the elements of `table` array are null pointers. You are not allowed to perform any kind of access through null pointers.

And this just doesn't make sense

```
   if(hash->table[item] == NULL)
   {
        hash->table[item]->K = K;
        hash->table[item]->I = I;
        return 0;
   }
```

Here you make an explicit attempt to write data through a null pointer.

You have to make sure a pointer points to a valid object before you make any attempts to access anything (write or read) through that pointer.

Comment: Okay so if I removed the line that makes them all NULL, would that make more sense?

Comment: @user081608: Just removing that line will not help. You have to make these pointers to point to somewhere meaningful. You have to *create* the object these pointers will point to. The question that comes to mind here is why did you make that `table` an array of *pointers* if you don't know where these pointers should point to? Why didn't you make it an array of `list_t` objects instead of pointers?

Comment: Sorry I may have just confused my self when making this function. Doesnt my malloc make room for the table size. Then table[0-n] should be alloced. I think I meant to make the line hash->table[i]->K = 0. Making all the keys = 0. But even so, Your saying that I need to make each array point somewhere?

Comment: @user081608: Your `malloc` allocates memory for the table itself. But you decided to store your `list_t` objects *outside* of that table, i.e. your table consists of *pointers* to `list_t` objects stored elsewhere. Your `malloc` does not allocate memory for these `list_t` object (how would it?). And you never create those `list_t` objects.

Comment: Oh so I have to alloc memory for the K and the I?

Comment: @user081608: You have to decide what you want to do. If you want to keep your table as is then you have to allocate memory for `list_t` objects as well. Independently. Each `list_t` object will contain your `K` and your `I`. So, no, you don't have to "allocate memory for `K` and `I`" specifically. You have to allocate your entire `list_t` objects, which will already contain `K` and `I`.

Comment: How would I go about doing that then? How would I alloc just for the list_t?

Answer (score 0):

In your function table_construct,when you malloc hash->table,you should do it like this.

```
hash->table = (list_t **)malloc(sizeof(list_t*) * table_size);
for (i=0;i<table_size;i++)
{
    hash->table[i] = (list_t *)malloc(sizeof(list_t));
}
```

You do that made then null,if you want to do like this.

```
memset(hash->table[i],0,sizeof(list_t));
```

Then you can use this judgment statement.

```
if(hash->table[item] != NULL)
{
    hash->table[item]->K = K;
    hash->table[item]->I = I;   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But what does the middle statement mean?

Comment: Fill block of memory with 0.